# How to keep the toolbars of Libre impress permanent

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, libreoffice

I am new to Libre impress and I am currently experiencing an issue about the toolbars. I want to keep the toolbars permanently in the libre impress without hiding time to time.
**Example : The Text Formatting toolbar only appears when I clicked on the text areas. But I want them to be appear in all the time. Is there any solution to my issue?**